# Pass a variable from a JavaScript page to a PHP page

Tags: jquery

I have JavaScript code that I copied from an online tutorial on read more topic, and I having been using it  without understanding what some of the codes does. Now I want to pass a variable ID from that script to another PHP page called main.php. How do I go about that?

JavaScript:

```js
(function($) {
  var id = "<?php echo variable; ?>"; //this line is where i want to set the variable and pass it to the main.php
  $.fn.loaddata = function(options) {
    // Settings
    var settings = $.extend(
      {
        loading_gif_url: "ajax-loader.gif", //url to loading gif
        end_record_text: "End of Feed", //no more records to load
        data_url: "main.php", //url to PHP page
        start_page: 1, //initial page
      },
      options,
    );

    var el = this;
    loading = false;
    end_record = false;
    contents(el, settings); //initial data load

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      //detact scroll
      if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $("#cont2").height()) {
        //scrolled to bottom of the page
        contents(el, settings); //load content chunk
      }
    });
  };
  //Ajax load function
  function contents(el, settings) {
    var load_img = $("<img/>")
      .attr("src", settings.loading_gif_url)
      .addClass("loading-image"); //create load image
    var record_end_txt = $("<div/>")
      .text(settings.end_record_text)
      .addClass("end-record-info"); //end record text
    if (loading == false && end_record == false) {
      loading = true; //set loading flag on
      el.append(load_img); //append loading image
      $.post(settings.data_url, { page: settings.start_page }, function(data) {
        //jQuery Ajax post
        if (data.trim().length == 0) {
          //no more records
          el.append(record_end_txt); //show end record text
          load_img.remove(); //remove loading img
          end_record = true; //set end record flag on
          return; //exit
        }
        loading = false; //set loading flag off
        load_img.remove(); //remove loading img
        el.append(data); //append content
        settings.start_page++; //page increment
      });
    }
  }
})(jQuery);

$("#results").loaddata();
```

Comment: `$.post` line: add your `id` in the data you want to pass (which are currently `{'page': settings.start_page}`).

Comment: please how can I do that

Comment: Check out Sandhya Nair's answer.

Answer (score 0):

With the below code, you may be able to read id as $_POST['id'] in main.php file.
I have added "data_id" to "settings" var
and then in $.post, i have passed an additional parameter like "id: settings.data_id"
Please check code below:

```
 (function($) {
    var id = "<?php echo $variable; ?>"; 
      $.fn.loaddata = function(options) {// Settings
    var settings = $.extend(
      {
        loading_gif_url: "ajax-loader.gif", //url to loading gif
        end_record_text: "End of Feed", //no more records to load
        data_url: "main.php", //url to PHP page
        start_page: 1, //initial page
        data_id: id
      },
      options,
    );

    var el = this;
    loading = false;
    end_record = false;
    contents(el, settings); //initial data load

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      //detact scroll
      if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $("#cont2").height()) {
        //scrolled to bottom of the page
        contents(el, settings); //load content chunk
      }
    });
  };
  //Ajax load function
  function contents(el, settings) {
    var load_img = $("<img/>")
      .attr("src", settings.loading_gif_url)
      .addClass("loading-image"); //create load image
    var record_end_txt = $("<div/>")
      .text(settings.end_record_text)
      .addClass("end-record-info"); //end record text
    if (loading == false && end_record == false) {
      loading = true; //set loading flag on
      el.append(load_img); //append loading image
      $.post(settings.data_url, { page: settings.start_page,id: settings.data_id}, function(data) {
        //jQuery Ajax post
        if (data.trim().length == 0) {
          //no more records
          el.append(record_end_txt); //show end record text
          load_img.remove(); //remove loading img
          end_record = true; //set end record flag on
          return; //exit
        }
        loading = false; //set loading flag off
        load_img.remove(); //remove loading img
        el.append(data); //append content
        settings.start_page++; //page increment
      });
    }
  }
})(jQuery);

$("#results").loaddata();
```

Comment: @Muna Please tick the answer correct if you got the issue fixed, it may be helpful for others